# knockout binding issue with enable property

Tags: binding, knockout.js

Consider the following:

```
<div data-bind="with: QuoteSelectedViewModel">
selected quote is : <span data-bind="text: ProductName"></span>
 <!-- ko foreach: CoverQuotesViewModel -->
<br/>    
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected"></input>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Label, enable: IsSelected"></input>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

with QuoteSelectedViewModel being:

```
 {
  "ProductName": "Perfect",
  "MonthPrice": 0,
  "QuarterPrice": 0,
  "BiannualPrice": 0,
  "YearPrice": 0,
  "CoverQuotesViewModel": [ {
        "ProductName": "Select",
        "Label": "Première Assistance 24h/24 (GRATUITE)",
        "IsVisible": true,
        "IsMandatory": true,
        "IsSelected": false,
        "IsChoice": false,
        "IsComposite": false,
        "YearPrice": "451451",
        "BiannualPrice": 0.49,
        "QuarterPrice": 0.2475,
        "MonthPrice": 0.08333333333333333,
        "Childs": [],
        "SelectedCoverQuote": null
     },
     {
        "ProductName": "Select",
        "Label": "Assistance PLUS 24h/24",
        "IsVisible": true,
        "IsMandatory": false,
        "IsSelected": true,
        "IsChoice": false,
        "IsComposite": false,
        "YearPrice": 36.0646,
        "BiannualPrice": 18.2182,
        "QuarterPrice": 9.20205,
        "MonthPrice": 3.098333333333333,
        "Childs": [],
        "SelectedCoverQuote": null
     }]
   }
```

See code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/j8HdW/4/

The problem is that checking and unchecking the checkboxes does not update the model, hence it does not update the textboxes.

To make the demo work, first click on the button 'get quotes' and then click on the button 'select quote'

Any idea what's wrong ?

**EDIT**

Ok, since the jsfiddle was overly complicated, here's a simplified version :http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/WCA5f/

Comment: Your sample code contains at least a hundred unrelated properties which has nothing to do with the `IsSelected` and just adding noise. Please reduce your example to the minimal case which demonstrates your problem!

Comment: Your fiddle is using resources from github. These do not work. Go to http://cdnjs.com/ and find a link for your resources there to use instead.

Comment: I've updated the demo with resources from cdnjs :http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/g82Tn/1/   I don't think that was the issue though.  Yes, the viewModel is pretty big, but it's already smaller than my production viewmodel. I wanted it to be as close as the original.

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle with only the relevant properties. Can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `IsSelected` is not an observable - [this worked for me](http://jsfiddle.net/WCA5f/1/)